# Does mysql python connector Cursor execute insert integer parameters with %d?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to insert data records into mysql database with mysql-python-connector.

The Cursor API (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) introduces parameters with `%s`.

I want to make sure that is there anything like `%d` for integer parameters ? Or just use `%s` for all kind of values.

Thanks

Comment: DB-API parameter substitution is not the same as string formatting: use `%s` for all _values_ being passed to the query.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, your comment is the same with my testings

Comment: See also https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Answer (score 2):

The mysql-python-connector only support `%s`